# How can I set a maximum file size for pages in Scanbot

Tags: cordova-plugins

In my app documents are scanned and handled by [Scanbot.io](https://scanbot.io/) and then uploaded to the backend server. Is there away to configure a maximum size for this documents in Scanbot.

I checked the documentation could not find a relevant setting

Ideally scanned Page objects that are too large for upload would be flagged in the detectionResult field and could be handled accordingly.

Are there any experiences on achieving something similar?

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but in my experience with Scanbot there are a few settings to help control resulting size.  It's not based on physical file size, but based on quality/resolution desires:

- In `initializeSdk` you can set a `storageImageQuality` setting.  I've
  heard that this can confidently be set at 80 since quality above that
  likely won't be noticeable to the eye.
- A `quality` option exists on calls to other functions too (e.g. `detectDocument`, `applyImageFilter`), similar to above
- The `startDocumentScanner` method has the ability to pass a `documentImageSizeLimit` object, which allows you to restrict the max width/height values.